# Vue.js index and length resetting on each page

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm having a strange problem that I can't solve. I wanted to add `index` number in for-each loop and count of total data in my vue.js component. I managed to do that, but my counter resets on every page within pagination, and `items.lenght` only counts data from current pagination page. I did the following:

```
<tr v-for="(item, index) in items" v-bind:key="item.id">
    <td>{{index + 1}}</td>
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

And to count all the data:

```
<div class="form-group">
    Total data: {{items.length}}
</div>
```

Everything is working fine of first page of pagination, but when I select second page, it only counts total data from that specific page, and the counter is starting from 1 again. To illustrate, on first page it shows me that I have total of 15 data (and I have around 300), and indexing is fine:

[image]

And If I go to second page, it still shows me the same total, and index is starting from 1 again, where I want it to continue (ex 16, 17..)

[image]

Part of the Vue.js component:

```
mounted() {
            this.getStatuses();
            this.getSchoolYears();

            if (this.items.length == 0) {
                this.loadPage(this.pagination.current_page);
                this.getObjects();
            }
        },
        methods: {
            getSaveStateConfig() {
                return {
                    'cacheKey': 'ApplicationComponent',
                };
            },
            addFilter(key, value) {
                this.filters = this.filters.filter(function (obj) {
                    return obj.key !== key;
                });
                this.pagination.current_page = 1;
                this.filters.push({key: key, value: value});
            },
            loadPageDebounce: _.debounce(function (page, parameters) {
                this.loadPage(page);
            }, 500),
            loadPage(page, parameters) {

                var parameters = '';
                this.filters.forEach(function (obj, index) {
                    parameters = parameters + '&' + obj.key + '=' + obj.value;
                });
                var $this = this;
                axios({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: '/api/applications?page=' + page + parameters,
                    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': window.csrfToken, 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
                })
                    .then(function (response) {
                        // console.log('resposne', response);
                        $this.items = response.data.data
                        $this.pagination.total = response.data.total;
                        $this.pagination.last_page = response.data.last_page;
                        $this.pagination.current_page = response.data.current_page;
                        $this.pagination.from = response.data.from;
                        $this.pagination.to = response.data.to;
                        $this.pagination.next_page_url = response.data.next_page_url;
                        $this.pagination.prev_page_url = response.data.prev_page_url;
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
            },
            loadData() {
                this.loadPage(this.pagination.current_page, this.filters);
            },
```

How to prevent this from happening when using vue.js pagination. All help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the best solution I guess, but it should work as a quick fix.

```
<tr v-for="(item, index) in items" v-bind:key="item.id">
    <td>{{(pagination.current_page*15)-15 + index+1}}</td>
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

**Edited better Solution as computed function to seperate view and logic:**

```
<tr v-for="(item, index) in items" v-bind:key="item.id">
    <td>{{getOverallIndex(index)}}</td>
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
</tr>

computed: {
    getOverallIndex: function(index) {
      return this.pagination.current_page*15)-15 + index + 1
    }
  }
```

Comment: As of indexing, this works just like intended. But, would this be a good solutions in the long time? This is the app in production with a lot of data, I'm afraid something will break in future?

Answer (score 2):

In your method you have that:

```
.then(function (response) {
         $this.items = response.data.data
         $this.pagination.total = response.data.total; // THERE
```

If you have good backend code you should get your total count here.

So try to `console.log($this.pagination.total)` after that function or `console.log(response.data.total)` in that function. If you have there 15 not 300 it's error on your backend. Maybe is problem for binding `this` on axios.

Let me know if you founded that.

Good luck!

Comment: `console.log($this.pagination.total)` returns total of `1285` records.

Comment: So there is your total data. You can print it where you need. Am I right? :D

Comment: You're right, I got the right output! Thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome. If its helpful please mark it as answer. Thank you.

Comment: Both answers helped me, is there a way to mark both as an answer?

Comment: Sadly not. Mark whatever answer helped you the most or that you felt was the most useful.

Answer (score 0):

try like

```
<tr v-for="(item, index) in items" v-bind:key="item.id">
    <td>{{items.indexOf(item)+1}}</td>
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Still getting the same output, index starts from 1 again on every page.